# How to access a var inside an API script [Next JS / React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to enable a success message after the form is complete using Mailerlite script.

How can I access variables inside a script to be able to show the success message?

`ml_webform_success_983964()`  this function works with onClick although it won't validate the field and just show the message. So maybe I need to access the `script`.

Someone, please help me I have no idea what I'm doing lol

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src =
      "https://groot.mailerlite.com/js/w/webforms.min.js?vaa2c3c2aced59c19bcfc4be08835b7b3";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  function ml_webform_success_983964() {
    var $ = ml_jQuery || jQuery;
    $(".ml-subscribe-form-983964 .row-success").show();
    $(".ml-subscribe-form-983964 .row-form").hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ml_webform_success_983964()` function.
For me, I append a script at the end of the page and the body of script was something like that:

```
function ml_webform_success_983964() {
  console.log("success")
}
```

and remove `onClick={ml_webform_success_983964}` in Register button because success will be handled by mailerlite script so this function should only run when submit is success.

Comment: This is still not working but thank you for trying to help :/  I even tried to use `next/script`